# How to install themeforest-claue-clean-minimal-magento-2-theme in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme

[image]Getting error of theme not found while installing the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have copied all the theme files into design folder.It looks some of the folder are files are missing.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming due to the theme files are not available there so you have to put all theme folders and file in Magento app/design and please follow the below documentation of ThemeForest.

https://www.magesolution.com/themes/claue/docs/m2/index.html#install-theme